# how to set answer to image in javascript quiz game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

This is a simple javascript quiz but i want to add images only as possible answers  and correct answers so ex the user clicks liberia image its the correct one
I tried fetching img src so i can set it in the answer array as text 
All i want is to put images as possible choices to the question and for them to be correct in the correct answer array
pls help 
beginner dev here

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function initialScreen() {
        startScreen = "<p class='text-center main-button-container'><a class='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block start-button' href='#' role='button'>Start Quiz</a></p>";
        $(".mainArea").html(startScreen);
    }

    initialScreen();

    $("body").on("click", ".start-button", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();  
        clickSound.play();
        generateHTML();

        timerWrapper();
    }); 

    for (var i = 1; i >= 20; i--) {
     var jad = document.getElementById(i); 
     var src = jad.src; 
    }

     $("body").on("click", ".answer", function(event){
        //answeredQuestion = true;//answeredQuestion = true;
        clickSound.play();  
         selectedAnswer = $(this).img()
        if(selectedAnswer === correctAnswers[questionCounter]) {
            //alert("correct");

            clearInterval(theClock);
            generateWin();
        }
        else {
            //alert("wrong answer!");
            clearInterval(theClock);
            generateLoss();
        }
    }); // Close .answer click

    $("body").on("click", ".reset-button", function(event){
        clickSound.play();
        resetGame();
    }); // Closes reset-button click

});  
//  Closes jQuery wrapper

function generateLossDueToTimeOut() {
    unansweredTally++;
    gameHTML = "<p class='text-center timer-p'>Time Remaining: <span class='timer'>" + counter + "</span></p>" + "<p class='text-center'>You ran out of time!  The correct answer was: " + correctAnswers[questionCounter] + "</p>" + "<img class='center-block img-wrong' src='img/x.png'>";
    $(".mainArea").html(gameHTML);
    setTimeout(wait, 4000);  //  change to 4000 or other amount
}

function generateWin() {
    correctTally++;
    gameHTML = "<p class='text-center timer-p'>Time Remaining: <span class='timer'>" + counter + "</span></p>" + "<p class='text-center'>Correct! The answer is: " + correctAnswers[questionCounter] + "</p>" + imageArray[questionCounter];
    $(".mainArea").html(gameHTML);
    setTimeout(wait, 4000);  //  change to 4000 or other amount
}

function generateLoss() {
    incorrectTally++;
    gameHTML = "<p class='text-center timer-p'>Time Remaining: <span class='timer'>" + counter + "</span></p>" + "<p class='text-center'>Wrong! The correct answer is: "+ correctAnswers[questionCounter] + "</p>" + "<img class='center-block img-wrong' src='img/x.png'>";
    $(".mainArea").html(gameHTML);
    setTimeout(wait, 4000); //  change to 4000 or other amount
}

function generateHTML() {
    gameHTML = "<p class='text-center timer-p'>Time Remaining: <span class='timer'>30</span></p><p class='text-center'>" + questionArray[questionCounter] + "</p><p class='first-answer answer'>A. " + answerArray[questionCounter][0] + "</p><p class='answer'>B. "+answerArray[questionCounter][1]+"</p><p class='answer'>C. "+answerArray[questionCounter][2]+"</p><p class='answer'>D. "+answerArray[questionCounter][3]+"</p>";
    $(".mainArea").html(gameHTML);
    }

    function wait() {
    if (questionCounter < 7) {
    questionCounter++;
    generateHTML();
    counter = 30;
    timerWrapper();
    }
    else {
        finalScreen();
    }
}

function timerWrapper() {
    theClock = setInterval(thirtySeconds, 1000);
        function thirtySeconds() {
        if (counter === 0) {
            clearIeLossDueToTimeOut();
        }nterval(theClock);
            generat
        if (counter > 0) {
            counter--;
        }
        $(".timer").html(counter);
    }
}

function finalScreen() {
    gameHTML = "<p class='text-center timer-p'>Time Remaining: <span class='timer'>" + counter + "</span></p>" + "<p class='text-center'>All done, here's how you did!" + "</p>" + "<p class='summary-correct'>Correct Answers: " + correctTally + "</p>" + "<p>Wrong Answers: " + incorrectTally + "</p>" + "<p>Unanswered: " + unansweredTally + "</p>" + "<p class='text-center reset-button-container'><a class='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block reset-button' href='#' role='button'>Reset The Quiz!</a></p>";
    $(".mainArea").html(gameHTML);
}

function resetGame() {
    questionCounter = 0;
    correctTally = 0;
    incorrectTally = 0;
    unansweredTally = 0;
    counter = 30;
    generateHTML();
    timerWrapper();
}

var startScreen;
var gameHTML;
var counter = 50000000000;
var questionArray = ["Which of these E-mails is fake? ", "What is the capital of Liberia?", "What is the capital of Taiwan?", "What is the capital of Japan?", "What is the capital of China?", "What is the capital of Turkey?", "What is the capital of Colombia?", "What is the capital of India?"];
var answerArray = [["<img id='1' src='img/fakeemail.png'>", "<img  src='img/liberia.png' class='answer'>", "<img src='img/taiwan.png' class='answer'>", "<img src='img/japan.png' class='answer'>"], ["Arthington","Monrovia","Tuzon","Marshall"], ["Tainan City", "Taichung", "Taipei", "Hsinchu"], ["Kyoto","Hiroshima","Tokyo","Osaka"], ["Hong Kong", "Macau", "Shanghai", "Beijing"], ["Ankara","Istanbul","Antalya","Bursa"], ["Medellin", "Bogota", "Cartagena", "Cali"], ["Mumbai","Hyderabad","Bangalore","New Delhi"]];
var imageArray = ["<img class='center-block img-right' src='img/fakseemail.png'>", "<img class='center-block img-right' src='img/liberia.png'>", "<img class='center-block img-right' src='img/taiwan.png'>", "<img class='center-block img-right' src='img/japan.png'>", "<img class='center-block img-right' src='img/china.png'>", "<img class='center-block img-right' src='img/turkey.png'>", "<img class='center-block img-right' src='img/colombia.png'>", "<img class='center-block img-right' src='img/india.png'>"];
var correctAnswers = ["img/fakeemail.png", "B. Monrovia", "C. Taipei", "C. Tokyo", "D. Beijing", "A. Ankara", "B. Bogota", "D. New Delhi"];
var questionCounter = 0;
var selecterAnswer;
var theClock;
var correctTally = 0;
var incorrectTally = 0;
var unansweredTally = 0;
var clickSound = new Audio("sound/button-click.mp3");
```

Comment: Is this correct, your correct answer array has this value `"img/fakeemail.png"`

Comment: Yes i tried using img src as i said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this all is in javascript and you could easily see the correct answers in the code anyway I guess that you could just give the correct image an class of for example "correct".

**Then change the code to something like:**

```
$(".answer").on("click", function(){
  if($(this).find("img").hasClass("correct")) {
      clearInterval(theClock);
      generateWin();
  }
  else {
      clearInterval(theClock);
      generateLoss();
  }
});
```